# I need to call a function from a third-party library from ASP.NET, but it must not be allowed to run asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

This is the situation:

- I use a third-party library to do some SPF checks
- The checks are done from an ASP.NET web site
- The third-party library uses lots of 'await/async' code, although I am calling a non-async method to do it
- Most of the time, w3wp (yes, the actual w3wp.exe) simply crashes with the following error ' Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated'.

I am assuming this is because the await/async grabbed a Thread from the threadpool which has some sort of illegal / weird identity on it, so I am wondering if there's any way to call a bit of code and tell .Net to 'forget about' async/await and just run it synchronously, on the same thread.

Comment: You could create a custom synchronization context, but that would only work *if* the library doesn't deliberately avoid the current synchronization context by calling `ConfigureAwait(false)`.Unfortunately, that does tend to be the recommended way of writing libraries.

Comment: When the issue is so specific to a library and usage, it would only be the vendor that can give you guidance (or confirmation that it can work with ASP.NET). I doubt the fact is that this library was not designed for ASP.NET context at all (as it seems to require certain impersonation setup).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It seems the library does not include ConfigureAwait anywhere in the source, so I will explore the possibility of a custom synchronization context. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution: somewhere in the product the user was being impersonated with identity.impersonate(), but the impersonation context was never .undo()'d. After making sure the identity.impersonate() was properly matched by an .undo(), the problem stopped occurring.

I did try making my own SynchronizationContext, but that didn't work in this instance, as passing on the impersonation just passed on the 'illegal' impersonation context too.